# Why does the following contain only str-3

Tags: c

The output of the following is "str-3,"  however I expect it to be "str-2,str-3,"

If I change snprintf to sprintf then this works how I expected it to; shouldn't snprintf and sprintf behave the same?

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    char str[64];

    str[0] = '\0';

    snprintf(str, 64, "%s%s,", str, "str-2");
    snprintf(str, 64, "%s%s,", str, "str-3");

    printf("%s\n",str);
}
```

Comment: if the source and destination overlap, it is UB

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The description of `snprintf` in the C standard (C99, 7.19.6.5) says:

> If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undeﬁned.

This is what happens here since `str` is used as both the input and output.

The same restriction applies to `sprintf`. The fact that it happened to work for you is just an accident, as can happen with undefined behavior.